# How to create a heatmap with numbers using Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, heatmap, leaflet.draw

I wish to create a heatmap like follows, with the number changes at different zoom level - the number can appear in a mouse-hover window instead of directly showing on the map:

```
    http://www.trulia.com/local/san-francisco-ca/tiles:1|points:1_crime
```

[image]

Any idea how to make this with Leaflet map?

EDIT:

I tried heatmap.js. But it cannot show the numbers on a map.

EDIT2:

I have a csv file with three columns:

```
    lat  lng  count
```

Any tips how to easily load it for 
[Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)?

Comment: Seems like this is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186247/how-to-create-a-heatmap-with-numbers-using-leaflet-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show points cluster layer use [k-mean](https://github.com/LukaszKrawczyk/density-clustering) clustering and for heatmap use [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/).

Both of these two modules can be used easily in any mapping library.

Comment: I tried heatmap.js, it does show the color, but it cannot show the corresponding numbers like the webpage mentioned in the OP. Any further tips?

Comment: @Osiris heatmap.js uses canvas 'createRadialGradient' function to render the heatmap. I am not aware if we can get the interpolated value from this module (heammap.js). If you want to show value on mouse over that should be with some logic i.e some type of interpolation (like kriging). Please explain your project requirement or doubt in detail so that a suitable approach can be suggested.

Comment: I have updated the question. We can add an additional layer of numbers/markers on top of the heatmap.js layer. :)

Comment: Yes leaflet's markerCluster is simple to implement. Regarding mouse over do you want to show the value of colors or point?

Comment: It will be great to show the value of colors, but I don't expect it if there is any noticeable performance penalty. I just need the numbers as shown in the screenshot of my question. http://www.trulia.com/local/san-francisco-ca/tiles:1|points:1_crime

Comment: In link you mentioned thematic layer (heat map with different colors) seems predefined polygons (parcel boundary or some other type) rendering. So for clustering use any density clustering algorithm or leaflet markerCluster.